# Changing color of SharePoint List rows

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to write some javascript to be able to read the date from one column of a SharePoint List. For example if in my date column (MonthNeeded) the date is 03/15 I want to be able to check if the date is < 30 days from today's date or <= 90 days from today's date and so on. When it checks this it will change the row color that corresponds with that date a certain color. Less than 30 days from today it will be red, greater than or equal to 30 days it will be orange, etc...

I wrote some code in Visual Studio because I unfortunately cannot use SharePoint designer with my instance of SP so I can't test my code real time.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function CheckStatus() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TD") // find all of the TDs
    var _dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.MonthNeeded)
    var now = Date();
    var nowPlus30 = new Date();
    nowPlus.setDate(now.getDate() + 30);

    var nowPlus90 = new Date();
    nowPlus.setDate(now.getDate() + 90);

    if (_dueDate == '' || !_dueDate) {
        return '';
    }
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        if (x[i].className == "ms-vb2") //find the TDs styled for lists
        {

            if( _dueDate <= nowPlus30 ) //find the data to use to determine the color
            {
                x[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'; // set the color
            }

            //repeat the above for each data value

            if (_dueDate <= nowPlus90) {
                x[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; // set the color
            }

            if (_dueDate > nowPlus30) {
                x[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; // set the color
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you are using SP2013, you should be using JSLink - http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/04/color-code-list-items-with-javascript-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 1):

I've used the date.js library in the past to do conditional formatting see: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/

Here's a snippet of my code:

```js
var created = oListItem.get_item('Created').toLocaleDateString();
var dateCreated = Date.parse(created);
var lastWeek = Date.today().add(-7).days();
var newIcon = '';
if (dateCreated >= lastWeek) {
      newIcon = "<span class='newIcon'> new!</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't run properly because you have some minor errors in your JS.

First, check that **nowPlus** is not defined, however you are trying to use it, and the function breaks, trowing an exception.

You should be using **nowPlus30** and **nowPlus90** when setting the date plus 30 days, and plus 90 days, respectively.

Also, check the line:

```
var now = Date();
```

You need to replace the above line with:

```
var now = new Date();
```

As Date is a JS object that needs to be initialized before using it.

Please check out the following fiddle for a reference :)

http://jsfiddle.net/canolucas/gmw9tr5h/

Comment: this helps but how would I let the function know the format of the date. In my column the dates are 03/15, 02/15, 04/15, etc... I know in C# we would use "MM/YY" but is that an option in javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get exactly what you need. You need to convert a Date to a formatted string? If so (assuming your date object is called objDate), you can use var month = objDate.getMonth() + 1;  var year = objDate.getFullYear(); var dateStr = pad(month) + "/" + year.substr(year.length - 2); your formatted string will be in the variable dateStr. NOTE: the pad function should look like this: function pad(n) { return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n; }

Comment: If you need to convert a date string (strDate) to a Date object, you can use : var dateArr = strDate.split("/"); var year = Number(dateArr[1]); var month = Number(dateArr[0]); var day = 1; var objDate = new Date(year, month, day); your date will be in the objDate variable